# How can I predict whether my cat is "dog-savvy?"

Tags: cats, dogs, introducing-pets

We are considering adding a dog to our household of 2 adults, 1 child, and 1 cat.

One of the rescue sites we like regularly posts dogs that are described as being good with "dog-savvy cats."

Without introducing my cat to a dog to see how things go, how can I predict whether my cat is dog-savvy?  It's unclear to me whether we should be uninterested in dogs described in this manner.

Comment: Have you asked the rescue for what they mean by "dog-savvy"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Dog-savvy" can mean a lot of things and is not always meant to mean the same thing across sites or even postings.  Even for the rescue site in question, it depends on the context of the specific rescue animal.

It can mean:

- Has direct experience with dogs and is able to co-exist with one
- Stands up to a dog instead of hiding or running away constantly
- Hides from a dog but does not exhibit negative anxiety-related behaviors
- Plays with a dog

Within the context of your specific cat and a specific dog, understanding the specific personalities.

If your cat tends to be very anxious when the environment is not calm, then it might not be "dog-savvy" around an energetic dog.

Most shelters will require a brief intro/test between the potential dog and your cat, at which point they will look for obvious signals in the behavior of the dog and cat that would indicate whether it is a bad fit.  Examples might include:

- Obvious signals of distress on the cat including ears back, growling and hissing constantly, or immediately fleeing
- Obvious signals of distress or prey drive in the dog including direct eye contact, ears back, etc.